# Find <a> tags using jquery with no span of particular text in it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find  tags which does not have span of particular text as child element.

```
HTML


      <div>
        <a class = "Enabled Select">
          <span>Text1</span></a>
        <a class = "EnabledSelect">
          <span>Text1</span></a>
        <a class = "Enabled Select">
          <span>DonotSelectme</span></a>
        <a class = "Enabled Select">
          <span>Text1</span></a>
        <a class = "Enabled Select">
          <span>DonotSelectme</span>
      <a class = "Enabled ImageLink">
          <span>DonotSelectme</span></a>
     <a class = "Enabled ImageLink">
          <span>SelectMe</span></a>
    </div>
```

Jquery so far

```
$link= `$("a.Enabled.Select").not(".ImageLink").not("span:contains('DonotSelectme')")
```

It should return three a tags back to me.

```
      <a class = "Enabled Select">             
      <a class = "Enabled Select">
     <a class = "Enabled Select">
```

Comment: Why is there just a random 2nd string in all the a elements? Why don't you close the a elements?

Comment: `class = "Enabled" "Select"` is invalid

Comment: none of your <a> tags are closed - this is also invalid!

Comment: Using valid HTML, and a little cleanup of strangeness, and it works fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/537qvwj8/

Comment: The HTML you have posted is nowhere near valid. Do yourself a favour and give jQuery a chance by getting rid of all the validation errors you will find at https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @adeneo I don't think your example is working fine, as per OP's request. It's returning every element regardless of whether it contains `DonotSelectme` or not.

Comment: @TylerRoper - works perfectly fine for me -> https://jsfiddle.net/537qvwj8/1/

Comment: @adeneo You're correct, I misunderstood the example and thought you meant to output only elements that satisfied the selection case. Your second fiddle was the slap on the head I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $link = $("a.Enabled.Select").not(".ImageLink").not(":has(span:contains('DonotSelectme'))")
```

This is what I was looking for